# A word that encompasses both hypermasculinity and hyperfemininity?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that encompasses both hypermasculinity and hyperfemininity.

The characters portrayed in movies such as *Grease* are strong examples of _________, as all the men have a heightened sense of masculinity while the women have a heightened sense of femininity.

Comment: Is it true that the characters in, e.g., **Grease** have "heightened" senses of masculinity and femininity? Aren't they more (gender-normative) representations of stereotypical men and women? (Not that this invalidates your question.)

Comment: _Sexual-stereotypes_? Men behave like real men, women behave like real women and small furry creatures from Alpha Centauri behave like _real_ small furry creatures from Alpha Centauri (with apologies to [Douglas Adams' original](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/46075-in-those-days-spirits-were-brave-the-stakes-were-high)).

Comment: If the term were _hypersexuality,_ the characters would not be examples
of hypersexuality.

Comment: *Sexual dimorphism* is the biological equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term **hypergender** applies.

Here's a paper on [hypergender ideologies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256933683_Assessing_Hypergender_Ideologies_Development_and_InitialValidation_of_a_Gender-Neutral_Measure_of_Adherence_to_Extreme_Gender-Role_Beliefs).

And a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=jxtMLGIdQ8cC&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=hypergender%20definition&source=bl&ots=hs7jcmQz_Z&sig=ACfU3U10ckFsqnmbKih0kL6EFSH--7eUwA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlgbzEuuvhAhUOTawKHVv9AY8Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=hypergender%20definition&f=false), which cites a definition of hypergender as:

> persons who exhibit very strong adherence to their gender stereotype.

Comment: "The characters portrayed in movies such as Grease are strong examples of *hypergender*, as all the men have a heightened sense of masculinity while the women have a heightened sense of femininity."

Comment: Wouldn't that be an adjective?

Comment: And the noun derived from *hypergender* would be...?